# Emitting Manual 'presenceUpdate' in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

i was wondering if i can emit an `presenceUpdate` as it require the presence class..

I know I can emit an manual even using [EventEmitter#emit()](https://EventEmitter#emit()) but I cannot get around how to do it with `presenceUpdate`

[docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-presenceUpdate)

Comment: Not sure what your problem is, you can't use .emit() on the event ? or you don't know what arguments to give to the event ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Voxlinou i dont know the arguments

Comment: you could use `new Discord.Presence(...)` and put any data you want on the ..., check the discord.js source code (src/structures/Presence) to see what the class askss for arguments and you'll know what to put on the Presence,, then do the exact same thing but change 1 element. I don't really know why you want to emit the presenceUpdate. If you have for example a log system just create a new activity with CustomRP on github or go offline/online to try it out